# How to excecute commands inside subdirectories of current directory in tcsh

Tags: tcsh

I am new to shell programming and using tcsh, i want to do the following.

i. Find out the subdirectories in the current directory(assume only subdirectories are present, nothing else, so that 'ls' is sufficient)

ii. Go into each of them one after another, and inside a folder named "abc", run a command present in a file command_file

Is the below valid. I'm confused about the syntax also:

```
set sub_TBs = `ls | awk '{split($0,a,":")'`;

foreach i (a) {

cd ./a[i]/abc 
./command_file;}
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach dir (`find * -type d -maxdepth 0`)
    cd $dir/abc
    ./command_file
    cd ../..
end
```

Naturally, that's only if `command_file` is executable. If not, then replace that line with `source command_file`.